# Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code works but it keeps giving me this error console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )**

Check the last line of my code is where I get the error. Thanks in advance.

```
function change_type(itemID) {
    window.location = "/store/basket.cfm?mode=select&itemID=" + itemID;
}

// gets pertinent mediums for a year...
function change_medium_list(award_year) {

    // clear previous contents...
    $("select#medium_name").empty();
    //console.log('cleared existing mediums');

    // do a JSON get......
    $.getJSON("_medium_list_by_year.cfm", {
        award_year: award_year,
        ajax: 'true'
    }, function(p) {
        var jsonList = (p);

        //alert(jsonList);
        var listItems = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++) {
        listItems += "<option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].optionValue + "'>" + jsonList.Table[i].optionDisplay + "</option>";
        }
        // Write the new values in...
        $("#medium_name").change(listItems);
        //console.log('written mediums');


        // this doesn't seem to refresg the content...
        // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
        $('.selectpicker').on('change', function() {
            var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
            alert(selected);
        });

    });
});  **// here is where I get the error. but if it change it to }; my code doesnt work.**
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the trailing bracket, so the last line looks like this

`};  //here is where I get the error. but if it change it to }; my code doesnt work.**`

Comment: Thanks! it does work that way, (as in I don't get the error message anymore) but for some reason my dropdown stops working if I do so?
It wont let me select a different option from the dropdown.

Comment: I don't have enough code to solve that problem. Is an onchange method running when you select from the drop-down? Does it interfere with the drop-down list in some way? The code you posted doesn't show what methods are attached to what events.

Comment: @user3507631 To be fair, this answer solves your question. You don't get an error anymore. The fact that it's not working properly is something else. Please provide some context: how that's called, maybe even a snippet of the json...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing bracket **and** the semicolon after the second function. Neither are needed.

```
);
```